# Javascript: timer number is increasing when scrolling page

Tags: javascript, html, timer

my web site some times will get really slow but I can't find out the reason immediately,
on the way of my debugging, I wanna know how many timer on my web site.

so I just type `console.log(setTimeout(() => 'hello world!'))`  in console panel to show the timer number of my page.
Ignore how much timer I original have, when I just type once and again, the timer number will increase 1 like I expected, but when I slightly **scroll my page** and to that again...

the number of my timer increase around **20**

I'm thinking maybe that's the mac book touch bar behavior, so I visit the home page of **Google**, use Element-panel remove all html items and add an empty but really height `div` into `body` tag, well, the timer of **Google** home page **will increase**, too

so I just create a simple and static html, here is all it has:

```
<div></div>
<style> div { height: 300vh; } </style>
<script>console.log('hello world!')</script>
```

when I scrolling the page, the timer number **won't** increase, so I'm sure that's not a mac touch bar behavior.

I know that's a pretty strange question.
does any one know what may cause that happened or what is that for?
or how to trace the trigger point of timer. thanks

Comment: How come you know the `timer count` using `console.log(setTimeout(() => 'hello world!'))`?

Comment: when you assign `setTimeout` or `setInterval` to a variable and use console to print   it, it will show the total number of all timer ever created. so the above codes is just combined "assign value" and "console.log"

Comment: due to the timer take at least 1 argument, the `() => 'hello world'` is just a simple placeholder function as its input argument

Comment: there's some code in your page that uses a setTimeout when scrolling - simple

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` returns a timer ID. It doesn't mean the previous timers are still running, just more timers have been used.

Google may use async scroll callbacks to load more content, which can create timers as you scroll.

Scroll event tends to fire multiple time per user interaction. If your scroll listener is expensive, [debounce](https://underscorejs.org/#debounce) or [throttle](https://underscorejs.org/#throttle) the event handler to limit the resource it consumes.

Comment: thanks for comment. I know that's the ID, but I don't remember I write any scroll event handler. no matter the timer is stop or not, I want to avoid the extra performance take of create new timer.

Comment: is there a way of tracking the event loop by timer ID?

Comment: Have you tried the [performance tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) of your browser's dev tool? It should give you a good idea of what code is being run and how much resource they are consuming.